# NSURL Display Text - Objective-C (Xcode)

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurl, social-framework

I have a NSURL displayed in a controller:

```
[controller addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stepit/id898652192?ls=1&mt=8"]];
```

It works, but I don't want to display the URL as the text. I want to have it say my App name, and clicking the link links to the correct URL listed above. Thoughts?

Comment: You mean like a hyper-link? A solution would be to create a UIButton, where the title text of the button is that of your desired app name, then the IBAction of this button does what you want it to do, which in this case is to go to the URL

Comment: It depends on what control you're using to display it.  A button is good.  If you're using a UITextView, you'll need to use an attributedString, etc.  What does `addURL` actually do now?

Comment: @Jeely Yes. I am aware of IBActions. The issue is that I need it shortened to put in a Facebook post that the user publishes.

Comment: @jeffamaphone The `addURL` code creates the link in the post, but has the **entire** link text. I would like to shorten this down.

Comment: Use a different SDK which allows you to specify something else (like HTML)...

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I have found that isn't possible to do exactly what I want. I am using https://bitly.com/ to shorten my URL. Thanks for all your support!